# Как отключить протокол SMBv2.0 (не затрагивая версию 2.1)?

Tags: windows, virustotal

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по таблице, протокол SMBv2.0 работает только для Windows Vista

Протокол SMBv2.1 работает только для Windows 7

Как отключить протокол SMBv2.0 не затрагивая протокол SMBv2.1 через реестр?

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters]
"SMB1"=dword:00000000
```

Данная мера требуется для блокировки связи с устаревшими версиями Windows

На официальном сайте не рекомендуют отключать вторую версию: [#ссылка](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1,-smbv2,-and-smbv3-in-windows-vista,-windows-server-2008,-windows-7,-windows-server-2008-r2,-windows-8,-and-windows-server-2012)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Строки из кода EternalBlue, он же WanaCry: [#источник](http://www.securitylab.ru/blog/personal/Morning/341825.php)